# Why is component props undefined (vue router)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am new to Vue and I'm trying to learn how to apply Vue router. I got normal routing to work no problem. When I try to use dynamic routing everything continued to work fine. When I tried to pass props to dynamic routes however my code breaks.

I'm using these cdn versions of Vue and Vue router which are the versions suggested by the official websites:
- https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js
- https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.0.0/dist/vue-router.js

The HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
  <nav>
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    <router-link to="/user/John">Name</router-link>
  </nav>
  <!-- route outlet -->
  <!-- component matched by route will render here -->
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

The JS

```
// Route components
  const Home = { template: '<div>Home</div>' };
  const About = { template: '<div>About</div>' };
  const User = { props: ['name'], template: `
    <div>
      <div>User {{ name }}</div>
      <button @click="checkName">Check</button>
    </div>`,
    methods: {
      checkName: function() {
        console.log('Params name: ' + this.$route.params.name);
        console.log('Props name: ' + this.name);
      }
    }
  };

  // Routes for router
  const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/home', redirect: Home },
    { path: '/about', component: About },
    { path: '/user/:name', component: User, props: true }
  ];

  const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: routes
  });

  const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      message: 'VueJS Router'
    },
    router: router
  });
```

When I navigate to the 'Name' page the static text renders fine but the dynamic text fails to load. I added a button that will log the value of name from props and from $route.params to the user. When clicked it turns out that the value of name in props is undefined but the value of name from params is correct. Why is this?

Comment: The `name` is a url param not a prop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you're sticking with VueRouter@2.0.0 or lower :**
The `name` that you expect is not passed as a prop but as a route param, [cf. Dynamic route matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes).

You need to access it from your template as follow : `$route.params.name`.

You could also use a computed value instead.

**If you can update VueRouter**
As stated in another answer, and according to the [release note of VueRouter@2.2.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/releases/tag/v2.2.0), passing down route params as props has only been introduced in v2.2.0, you were using v2.0.0. If you would like to use props you would need to update to (at least) v2.2.0.

Comment: Im really just copying the code from here. Im not sure why I’m not getting the desired result. How would I pass the value as a prop? https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode

Comment: Since you're using it as your `router-view` you can't just pass it as a prop once it's available. I'm still unsure about why you would absolutely need it as a prop if you have access to it from somewhere else

Comment: I don’t need it to be a prop it’s just the documentation said I could use a prop and I couldn’t figure out why it wasn’t working. Also here https://medium.com/frontend-fun/vuejs-routing-with-vue-router-1548f94c0575 I originally copied this verbatim and it still did not work. I must be missing something

Comment: That's intriguing, what you have should theoretically be working as expected. Have you tried to use  `Vue.use(VueRouter)` before creating the router?

Comment: I did not try using `Vue.use(VueRouter)`. I assumed that passing the router to my Vue instance (as stated in the docs) would be sufficient

Comment: Since it is directly used in the browser, it is used when the script tag is evaluated. I'm still stunned by the fact that this is not working at all despite being the correct approach to get it as a prop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171729/discussion-between-thenewguy-and-vivick).

Answer (score 0):

CDN link provided on the Vue Router installation page was outdated. Instead of:

https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.0.0/dist/vue-router.js

use:

https://unpkg.com/vue-router@3.0.1/dist/vue-router.js

Answer provided here:
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/why-is-component-props-undefined-vue-router/34929/5